# EXCEL - split Australian addresses into multiple column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an address in the below format:

```
67 Sydney Road 
Coburg 
Vic 3058
```

Is there a way that I split this address into 4 columns in excel itself such as:

```
Address Line 1 : 67 Sydney Road
City: Coburg
State: VIC
Postcode: 3058
```

All my addresses are formatted in a similar way. There actually is a carriage return in between the address line and city as well as the city and state.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could also write a matrix function that returns an array. Select four cells in a row, enter the formula

```
=addr(<cell-reference>)
```

and submit with `<shift><cntrl><return>`. The matrix function will then return the four lines of the input field in four separate columns in one row which you can then process according to your requirements.

The function `addr()` could be something like this

```
Function addr(v)
Dim i%, a
a = split(v, Chr(10))  ' option base 0 is in effect ...
ReDim out(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(a) + 1)
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
 out(1, i + 1) = a(i)  ' matrix functions need to return a 2D array
Next i
addr = out             ' this puts the separated values into your table
End Function
```

[image: function addr in VB macro editor]

Comment: I tried this method but all I get is #NAME? in all four columns

Comment: You need to have this function in the 'Modules' section of your workbook, see my edited post.

Comment: Something must have escaped me. I rewrote the script again and this time it worked. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use regex for this task. But first, a more simple method:

You could use the `Split(text_string, delimiter)` method to separate the parts. 
First you could split at the carriage return, then you could split at the whitespaces to separate the data itself.

But this method has one big disadvantage if you have "unclean" data, with more than one whitespace or other problems. When you have more than one whitepsace, you would have to use `Trim()` to get rid of them.

To be safe and to be able to parse "more complex" cases, I would recommend to use regular expressions. It's more complicated to learn, but you have quite more possibilities to parse texts. A big advantage is that you can group your results, so you can work with group  names like "street" or "city". That is much easier to read than Array[0].

Comment: I have been reading about regex and it does sound like the way to go. However, I am trying to complete this task before tomorrow morning and I don't think I can write something quick enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are totally sure that the format of the address will remain the same then this should solve your problem-

```
Sub splitAddress()
    Dim WrdArray() As String
    Dim WrdArray2() As String
    Dim text_string, temp, strg As String
    text_string = "67 Sydney Road\nCoburg\nVic 3058"
    WrdArray() = Split(text_string, "\n")
    temp = Split(text_string, "\n")(2)
    WrdArray2() = Split(temp, " ")
    ReDim Preserve WrdArray(1)
    ReDim Preserve WrdArray(3)
    WrdArray(2) = WrdArray2(0)
    WrdArray(3) = WrdArray2(1)
    strg = "Address Line 1 : " & WrdArray(0) & vbNewLine & "City: " & WrdArray(1) & vbNewLine & "State: " & WrdArray(2) & vbNewLine & "Postcode: " & WrdArray(3)
    MsgBox strg
End Sub
```